# How to make Rsync only allow download but not upload

Tags: centos, rsync

I know that i can add in Rsync's config file

```
read only = no
```

But when I use the synchronization command on the client, rsync tells me

```
ERROR: module is read only
```

If I change the value of read only to “no”, the client will automatically upload files when synchronizing files with the server

So what should I do to allow the client to only download changed files from the server and not allow local files to be uploaded to the server when synchronizing files with the server?

My Server System : CentOS 7

Client System : Windows use cwRsync

Comment: Doesn't rsync do this by default? It isn't bidirectional.

Comment: rsync has also a client server structure, in case a path is writable it may a chance that clients accidentally update the server. if you need to do have write access i would suggest to create share-r and share-rw for easier differencing, by the way he is meaning the rsync:// server itself, not rsync over ssh i guess